# Unable to open Word template on Server VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

My below code is working locally and we have Microsoft Word installed on the server. In my solution project we have a folder called 'Patients' and under it a word template called 'Test1'.

```
     Protected Sub btnPatientDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim fLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Patients/Test1.docx")
        
        Dim id As String = Request.QueryString("ID")

        Dim applicationWord = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()

        applicationWord.Visible = True

        Dim doc As Document = applicationWord.Documents.Open(fLocation)

        doc.Activate()


        Dim patientFirstName = (From x In dbo.Patient Where x.ID= id Select x.firstname).FirstOrDefault()

        Dim patientSurnameName = (From x In dbo.Patient Where x.ID = id Select x.lastname).FirstOrDefault()

        doc.Content.Find.Execute("PATIENTS FULL NAME", False, True, False, False, False, True, 1, False, patientFirstName + " " + patientSurnameName, 2,False, False, False, False)

        doc.Content.Find.Execute("Date", False, True, False, False, False, True, 1, False, Today.Date(), 2,False, False, False, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Although this has no direct bearing on your issue, you really should take time to learn the difference between a document (docx) and a template (dotx). Your code is opening a document (Documents.Open + docx file), not creating one from a template (Documents.Add + dotx file) - which is what you really should be doing.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  Getting exceptions of some nature?  If so, what and were

Comment: No exception. When I test the published web application the button does nothing! But as I mentioned it works locally so I have no idea what's wrong and how to debug

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it wasn't working, you should be having some sort of exception, are you sure that isn't being caught some where up the call stack?  Things I would try 1) Make sure fLocation is vaild, check the file exists before trying to open it (Might have a path problem).  2) Ensure correct version of word and dependencies are installed on your server and you can open that file directly. 3)  Attach the remote debugger and step through the code on the server